# Ehcache non-blocking clear / refresh?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Is it possible to have Ehcache serve cached results until the clear/update cache call is complete?

Say I have a cache which expires every 10 minutes and takes 30 seconds to reconstruct..

Is it possible for my first call after the 10 minute clearcache call to avoid the long wait on a fresh response?

thanks!

Comment: There was Refresh ahead in Ehcache2 but apparently not Ehcache3.. I am looking how to do this for Ehcache3.